# How to implement 'BackSpace', 'arrow' in Xterm.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xtermjs

I'm designing a web which include a terminal using Xterm.js and would like transfer the string to the server. I can type some string on it but can't use 'backspace', 'delete', 'home' functions.

I tried to do that functions by myself, but there are a lot function need to do.

e.g. Backspace

```
term.on('key', (key, ev) => {
    const code = key.charCodeAt(0);
    if(code == 127){   //Backspace
        term.write("\b \b");
    }
});
```

I could delete the last character, but can't delete inside the string...
Are these functions to be done by myself? Is there a more convenient module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In short, yes. You have to manipulate the buffer yourself, there are no methods to do this for you.

#### TL;DR

I am running into the same issue actually. It appears all of this is buffer driven and I haven't quite figured out how to do this in a natural way yet, but...

To simulate a left arrow:

```js
this.child.write('\x1b[D');
```

You can also add any unicode character by hex: \uhhhh

Comment: When I get farther I will update my post. If you get any farther please also post a solution.

Comment: Maybe we could reference this [sample](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/xtermjs-local-echo-ioannis-charalampidis)

Comment: Actually @Assam that isn't a bad looking code base. I was actually wring something like this as well for my app. Instead f continuing on with what I have, I may try to implement this and offer some guidance.

What's your stack look like? I am using Angular8.

Comment: Why the don't implement it natively ?

Comment: \x1b[D\x1b[P performs the action of moving the cursor one position to the left and then deleting the character at that new position.